# Fastest way to create vector with size (not capacity)?

Tags: rust

```
let mut data = Vec::<::std::os::raw::c_char>::with_capacity(s);
data.set_len(s);//unsafe
```

this is how I'd make a vector with a specific size. However, `set_len` is unsafe. I just need a slice to fill things into, but since it has dynamic size, I need to use a vector.

Is there a way to create a vector with a size, not a capacity, so I can pass it like this: `data.as_mut_slice()`?

Comment: The issue with the above code is that `set_len`'s safety requirement is that the elements are *initialized*, this doesn't do that. Along with that, slices can only reference fully initialized elements, so you can't safely get a `&mut [i8]` in order to fill the `Vec`. What you do to fill it will either be through `*mut i8` plus a `usize` length or a `&mut [MaybeUninit<i8>]`.

Comment: You might be interested in [Vec::spare_capacity_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.spare_capacity_mut). It's nightly-only for now, however.

Comment: what is wrong with `vec![0u8;32]`?